# Get image dimension after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, domready

I have a project that needs to get the logo's dimension and adjust its position accordingly. From what I understand, all the elements on the page should be ready for use right after `$(document).ready` or `onload` event. I also tried to put the script before the closing body tag to make sure I can get everything. I use jQuery `$(element).width` and `$(element).height` to measure the logo image.

However, I am not getting these value every time: I console log these two values. Sometimes, it shows me zero which I **guess** the image tag is loaded, but the actual image is still loading. I am so confused because I search online, they all say all the elements should be ready if I use DOM ready or put the script tag in the end.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623172/how-to-get-image-size-height-width-using-javascript

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('#img').load(function() {
// Handler for .load() called.
});
```

Comment: It calls after each time the image adds to dom.have you got the breakpoint inside the method??

Answer (score 0):

> all the elements on the page should be ready for use right after $(document).ready or onload event. I also tried to put the script before the closing body tag to make sure I can get everything.

No, the `$(document).ready` event resp. embedding the script as last element in body only guarantee that the DOM structure is build up already. That does **not** mean that external resources referenced by any elements have already finished loading – the only event that guarantees that is the `load` event.

The jQuery docs explicitly warn about combining `$(document).ready` and “old school” load event handling (meaning onload attribute on body or window.onload) – so you should use [`.on('load', handler)`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) instead. But be aware of the cave-ats of that regarding images that the docs also mention.